# Cassandra READ requests dropping

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have a column family as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE keyspace.tableName (
    key text PRIMARY KEY,
    A blob,
    B text,
    C text,
    D blob,
    "E" text
    H int
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.2
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 7776000
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 3600
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

While making read requests with query:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, WRITETIME(A), WRITETIME(B) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE KEY  = ?;
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:88)
```

This is a huge cluster handling billions of requests per day. I only get this in less than 0.1% of the requests. My 99th percentile is fine. GC is less than 1 sec but I do see some READ messages being dropped in tpstats. Median SSTable count is less than 3. My queries are such that I don't read the same key again for some time, so my key cache hit rate is less than 10%. My read request timeout is 200ms.

Could anyone please give me any pointers on how to debug this?

Comment: The best place to start is by checking the node `system.log` and `debug.log` for cassandra log directory (usually `/var/log/cassandra` on package installs). Check at the same time you see the error in the client for all the obvious things like `ERROR` or `WARN` messages, correlating the local time on the client to the server time (if they are in different time zones)

Comment: When you say your "read request timeout" is 200ms, are you talking about `read_request_timeout_in_ms` in `casandra.yaml`? That would be pretty low for most clusters (default is 5000), and would definitely lead to read timeouts. This setting is typically set to be {timeout >> nominal GC pauses}.

Comment: @markc I've tried that. There were only a few exceptions that were IOException - connection reset by peer. But they were too low in number.

@AdamHolmberg yes I'm talking about `read_request_timeout_in_ms`. Even if I keep it above 200ms, my driver will timeout which is set to 250ms. How can I log the requests which are being dropped?

Comment: if you have a GC that lasts 200ms you will get a dropped read and a timeout. Do you have any GCs near 200ms? Maybe include `nodetool tablestats` output incase something outta norm. Id leave timeouts at 5s for now, on client too. Can set client side spec retry to 100ms or something and just sit on executeAsync for 200ms vs waiting for OperationTimeout

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Thanks for your reply. My GC pauses median is around 400ms. Max was 900. I'll try what you are suggesting. The timeout we set on datastax driver is for each request, right? Not combined. You think 100ms timeout with 2 retries is better than 200ms with a single retry? My SLAs does not allow anything more than 200.

Comment: Then set (driver side) speculative retry to 100ms. Otherwise a coordinator GC will kill your SLA

Comment: @ChrisLohfink My speculative delay is already set to 100ms, spec max=1, consistency = LOCAL_ONE, read.timout = 250ms. Any comments?

Comment: on driver or on table? dont set read timeout to 250ms, that wont work

Comment: @ChrisLohfink on the driver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180467/discussion-between-heisenberg-and-chris-lohfink).